# Kentico Staging Sync InvalidOperationException: WSE563

Tags: kentico, staging

For 3 years I have been running ***Kentico 8.2.48*** with a functional staging environment, pushing daily content changes to a production server without any issues. Both servers were running ***Windows Server 2012 R2***.

I recently did the incremental upgrade to ***Kentico 11.0***, and deployed both environments to new servers with ***Windows Server 2016***. The headaches of the upgrade notwithstanding, both environments are functional but I am unable to sync the staging tasks, as I encounter the following exception:

```
Message: Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.SecurityFault: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized ---> System.InvalidOperationException: WSE563: The computed password digest doesn't match that of the incoming username token.
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameTokenManager.VerifyHashedPassword(UsernameToken token, String authenticatedPassword)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameTokenManager.VerifyPassword(UsernameToken token, String authenticatedPassword)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameTokenManager.VerifyToken(SecurityToken token)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.WebServiceAuthorization.VerifyToken(SecurityToken token)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenManager.LoadXmlSecurityToken(XmlElement element)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenManager.LoadXmlSecurityToken(XmlElement element)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenManager.GetTokenFromXml(XmlElement element)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Security.LoadToken(XmlElement element, SecurityConfiguration configuration, Int32& tokenCount)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Security.LoadXml(XmlElement element)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Security.CreateFrom(SoapEnvelope envelope, String localActor, String serviceActor)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.ReceiveSecurityFilter.ProcessMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Pipeline.ProcessInputMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.FilterRequest(SoapEnvelope requestEnvelope)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

Exception type: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException
Stack trace: 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.Server.SyncServerWse.ProcessSynchronizationTaskData(String stagingTaskData)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.Server.SyncServerWse.ProcessSynchronizationTaskData(IStagingTaskData stagingTaskData)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.SyncClient.RunTask(StagingTaskInfo taskObj)

Synchronization client error: Exception occurred: Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.SecurityFault: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized ---> System.InvalidOperationException: WSE563: The computed password digest doesn't match that of the incoming username token.
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameTokenManager.VerifyHashedPassword(UsernameToken token, String authenticatedPassword)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameTokenManager.VerifyPassword(UsernameToken token, String authenticatedPassword)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameTokenManager.VerifyToken(SecurityToken token)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.WebServiceAuthorization.VerifyToken(SecurityToken token)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenManager.LoadXmlSecurityToken(XmlElement element)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenManager.LoadXmlSecurityToken(XmlElement element)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenManager.GetTokenFromXml(XmlElement element)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Security.LoadToken(XmlElement element, SecurityConfiguration configuration, Int32& tokenCount)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Security.LoadXml(XmlElement element)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Security.CreateFrom(SoapEnvelope envelope, String localActor, String serviceActor)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.ReceiveSecurityFilter.ProcessMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Pipeline.ProcessInputMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.FilterRequest(SoapEnvelope requestEnvelope)
at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)Synchronizing 'Update page Sandbox' task
```

I have tried suggestions like [this one](https://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f65/fp18/t41229/staging-service-error-(wse563)) and [this one](https://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f56/t29588/staging-synchronization-fail), but even after adding the ***App Setting*** to the ***config file*** and ***changing the credentials*** TWICE to make sure they were the same between the environments, I am still unable to synchronize tasks.

Any suggestions would be helpful, I have some very unhappy users. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a web farm setup?

Comment: No, just a single server

Comment: The error may be a red herring. I restored the backups and staging works fine on our servers (at Kentico). So, maybe WSE3 is not installed/configured on the new machine or there is something on the network - firewall, proxy which is tampering the requests.